Postgresql "Resource temporarily unavailable"
I'm writing because I'm having a strange behaviour with my Postgresql installation (16.2).
The installation was done by compiling the source files as the installation is done on an AIX server configured with PowerHA.
The server has associated 64 GB of ram and 1 Power10 processor (s1024). The average usage is 20 GB ram and 30% processor.
In this installation, there are five fairly small databases (the largest is several GB), but there are several clients connecting simultaneously. The problem I am experiencing is that at peak times in the PostgreSQL logs I see ‘could not fork new process for connection: Resource temporarily unavailable’.
From the machine logs and performance data, however, I do not see any resource saturation that would cause this situation.
config file
- Memory -
shared_buffers = 1GB                    # min 128kB
                                        # (change requires restart)
#huge_pages = try                       # on, off, or try
                                        # (change requires restart)
#huge_page_size = 0                     # zero for system default
                                        # (change requires restart)
#temp_buffers = 8MB                     # min 800kB
#max_prepared_transactions = 0          # zero disables the feature
                                        # (change requires restart)
# you actively intend to use prepared transactions.
work_mem = 16MB                         # min 64kB
#hash_mem_multiplier = 2.0              # 1-1000.0 multiplier on hash table work_mem
maintenance_work_mem = 16MB             # min 1MB
#autovacuum_work_mem = -1               # min 1MB, or -1 to use maintenance_work_mem
#logical_decoding_work_mem = 64MB       # min 64kB
#max_stack_depth = 2MB                  # min 100kB 

ulimut -a
core file size              (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size               (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size                   (blocks, -f) unlimited
max memory size             (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                          (-n) unlimited
pipe size                (512 bytes, -p) 64
stack size                  (kbytes, -s) unlimited
cpu time                   (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes                  (-u) unlimited
virtual memory              (kbytes, -v) unlimited

Any ideas
I would like to arrive at a solution where there is not that kind of disruption and errors.

You will need to add the complete error message as well as the log entries immediately preceding the error to your question text.

Hi @AdrianKlaver unfortunatly I do not have more logs, on the log file I can also find a lot of this rows but no more information. Is there way to set up more logging?

Read What to log. It would also help to look at the OS system log to see if there is relevant information there.

Generally this error is due to exceeding the ulimit of the postgres user or due to lack of memory. Can you share max_connections value?

Hi, max connections are 300.

You might have hit an OS-limit called maxuproc.
Query:
/usr/sbin/lsattr -E -l sys0 | grep maxuproc

Set (as root):
/usr/sbin/chdev -l sys0 -a maxuproc=1000

Also check the value of ulimit -u (which corresponds to RLIMIT_NPROC with system-call getrlimit).

Hi, i've passed numer of allowed processes per user from 128 to 1000.... I will update you if now it's working or if nothing changed.
